# React Input Mask como colocar o nono dígito?

Tags: javascript, react

Baixei o pacote npm i react-text-mask --save fiz o import em meu arquivo Contact porém por padrão ele sai assim (55) 5555-5555 estou com dificuldades em colocar este padrão (55) 5 5555-5555

Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão de como fazer esse procedimento ?

Meu código está assim:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <MaskedInput
      mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Enter a phone number"
      guide={false}
      id="my-input-id"
      onBlur={() => {}}
      onChange={() => {}}
      />
 </div>
```

Comment: Vc quer colocar os dois padrões?

Comment: Apenas um. Este (55) 5 5555-5555

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inclua um novo dígito `/\d/` e um espaço no padrão:

```
                              nono dígito  espaço
                                       ↓    ↓
mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
```